# cannot pass a variable from a function in a class to another function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, timer

I asked part of this question about a week ago and got voted down so I have spent the time working at it to resolve it. I have worked out how to do the first part which was passing between a UIPicker and a function. I have created a class calculateTime() and inside is my function which accepts an array as a parameter. This then calculates a number which I label count.
What I need to do next is pass count to the update() function so I can update my text label with a counting down timer. No matter where I put this function I can't get it to work. If it's inside the class I get a selector error. If its outside the class I can't get the value of count to it. It gets overridden by the value I set at the top of the code. I am pasting all of the code here. I hope someone can help me here, I am beyond frustrated with myself not being able to work this out.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,     UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var dep: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var arrivesAt: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var departsFrom: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var arr: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!



var pickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()

var timer: NSTimer!

var count = 2

var arrayTimes = [""]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    calculateTime().refreshView(["5:45", "6:35", "7:00", "7:30", "7:50", "8:20", "8:40", "9:15", "10:10", "11:10", "12:40", "14:15", "14:50", "15:40", "16:10", "17:10", "17:40", "18:40", "19:25", "20:50"])

    picker.hidden = true

    dep.delegate = self

    dep.resignFirstResponder()
    arr.resignFirstResponder()

    //Picker

    // Connect data:
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self


    // Input data into the Array:
    pickerData = [["larkspur", "saulsalito", "san francisco", "fisherman's wharf", "giants stadium", "tiburon", "vallejo", "alameda", "harbor bay", "jack london", "south s.f."],
        ["san francisco", "saulsalito", "larkspur", "fisherman's wharf", "giants stadium", "tiburon", "vallejo", "alameda", "harbor bay", "jack london", "south s.f."]]

}



//Mark - Location Delegate Methods



struct MyViewState {
    static var count = 8
}



class calculateTime {

    var timesArray:[String] = []

    var timer: NSTimer!

    var count: Int = 0

    func refreshView(array: [String]) {


        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
        let hour = components.hour
        let minutes = components.minute
        let currentTime = "\(hour)" + ":" + "\(minutes)"

        self.timesArray = array

        print(timesArray)

        // create a method to convert your time to minutes
        func stringToMinutes(input:String) -> Int {
            let components = input.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
            let hour = Int((components.first ?? "0")) ?? 0
            let minute = Int((components.last ?? "0")) ?? 0
            return hour*60 + minute
        }

        //create an array with the minutes from the original array
        let timesMinutesArray:[Int] = timesArray.map { stringToMinutes($0) }

        let dayMinute = stringToMinutes(currentTime)
        // filter out the times that has already passed
        let filteredTimesArray = timesMinutesArray.filter{$0 > dayMinute }

        // get the first time in your array
        if let firstTime = filteredTimesArray.first {
            // find its position and extract it from the original array
            let nextDeparture = timesArray[timesMinutesArray.indexOf(firstTime)!]   //  "15:40"


            let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


            let dateMakerFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateMakerFormatter.calendar = userCalendar
            dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"



            // How many hours and minutes between now and the next ferry

            dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"
            let startTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString(currentTime)!
            let endTime = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString(nextDeparture)!
            let hourMinuteComponents: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Minute]
            let timeDifference = userCalendar.components(
                hourMinuteComponents,
                fromDate: startTime,
                toDate: endTime,
                options: [])

            let difference = (timeDifference.hour*60) + (timeDifference.minute)

            var count = difference

            print(count)  //this returns correctly


           timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: ViewController(), selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)




        }


    }

}


//Picker

// The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(picker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(picker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(picker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[component][row]
}


//Show picker wen text field is click in
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textfield: UITextField) -> Bool {
    dep.resignFirstResponder()
    arr.resignFirstResponder()
    self.dep.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.arr.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    picker.hidden = false

    return false

}

//Make text uneditable
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return false
}


// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(picker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
    print("/[component][row]")

    let fromto = pickerData[component][row]


    print(fromto)

    if component == 0 {

        var count = calculateTime().count

        arr.text = "san francisco"

        dep.text = pickerData[component][row]

        calculateTime().refreshView(["5:45", "6:35", "7:00", "7:30", "7:50", "8:20", "8:40", "9:15", "10:10", "11:10", "12:40", "14:15", "14:50", "15:40", "16:10", "17:10", "17:40", "18:40", "19:25", "20:50"])

        print("help")

       self.countDownLabel.text = "\(count)"

        print(count)

    }

    else {

        dep.text = pickerData[component][row]
    }



    picker.hidden = true;
}


func pickerView(picker: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(41/255.0), green: CGFloat(100/255.0), blue: CGFloat(226/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )
    pickerLabel.text = pickerData[component][row]
    // pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: pickerLabel.font.fontName, size: 15)
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 20) // In this use your custom font
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 36.0
}



func update() {


    if count == 1{
        //self.minutes.text = "minute"
        print("did change")
    }

    if(count > 0)
    {
        //countDownLabel.text = String(count--)

        print(count)
    }

    else if (count == 0)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        print("ended")
        calculateTime().refreshView(["5:45", "6:35", "7:00", "7:30", "7:50", "8:20", "8:40", "9:15", "10:10", "11:10", "12:40", "14:15", "14:50", "15:40", "16:10", "17:10", "17:40", "18:40", "19:25", "20:50"])

    }



}
```

}

Comment: There is a general misunderstanding: Any time you write `calculateTime()` or `ViewController()` you're creating a brand new instance of the type respectively, all instances are different objects. And if you don't declare a property to get a strong reference to one of the instances that instance is deallocated immediately after the enclosing method exits. And the `NSTimer` in `calculateTime()`  is not identical to that one in your `ViewController`. I'd like to encourage you to read the basics about classes and instances

Comment: I know, I have bought books, read articles, read the apple docs, watched hours of online tutorials but I still am struggling. I want to understand this, but I am yet to find anything that explains classes, instances etc. in a way I can understand it,  so i just try to learn by doing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the count variable at the very top of the file so that it is accessible within the file by all functions. This way you will only have one instance of count and you can update it from anywhere within the entire file. i.e. At the top of the file :

```
var count : Int = calculateTime().count
```

Then you can just access count as you do within the

```
update()
```

function.

If they are in separate classes then you would need to create an instance of that class, or alternatively, have an instance of that class already passed in. For example, if count was initialised in class A :

```
public class A {
    var count : Int = 0
}
```

If you wanted to then access the variable from class B, you could do as follows:

```
public class B {
    var classA : A = A()

    print("Count : \(classA.count)")
}
```

This would give you access to the count, for the instance of A that you have created. Alternatively, when creating the instance of class B, you could pass the appropriate instance of class A when initialising. For example

```
public class C {
    var a : A = A()
    var b : B = B(class : a)
}

public class B {
    var count : Int

    init(class : A = A()) {
        count = class.count
    }
}
```

Also, bare in mind that in OOP, you would probably want to use getters and setters, rather than just exposing the count and make the count private. i.e.

```
public class A {
    private var _count = 0

    var count : Int {
        get {
            return _count
        }

        set {
            if newValue != _count {
                _count = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    var classA : A = A()

    classA.count = 2 // Would set the count of class A, for the particular instance you have created as 2
}
```

This would also give you access to the variable. Also, if this does not help you, take a look at delegates & protocols, you can also pass variables this way.